# Google Short Url Api returns encoded url

Tags: php, facebook, sharing, google-url-shortener

I'm trying to get a short url for **http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=** (for facebook sharing) using Google shorten url API. The problem appears when it's return the short URL like http://goo.gl/xxxxx but the long url behind is **https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&amp%3Bp%5Burl%5D=** and this doesn't work in facebook. Any idea to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode` or `urldecode` to decode the url.

Comment: This is not the right approach because the problem is the shortened URL, which resolves to the encoded one.